# calculate the order of the subgroup of n-th residues mod n^2

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

Suppose $n=pq$ where $p,q$ are prime. A number $z$ is said to be a $n$th-residue modulo $n^2$ if there exists $y\in \mathbb{Z}_{n^2}^*$ such that $z = y^n \bmod n^2$.

It's claimed by [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.112.4035&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that

> the set of $n$-th residues is a multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{n^2}^*$ of order $\phi(n)$.

It's easy to verify that $n$-th residues form a subgroup. But how should one go about calculating its order?

Answer (score 0):

One way to see it is the following (I assume $p \neq q$).

First $\mathbb{Z}_{n^2}^*$ is a group of order $\phi(n^2) = \phi(p^2q^2) = pq(p-1)(q-1) = pq \phi(pq) = n\phi(n)$.

Now consider the group homomorphism $f: \mathbb{Z}_{n^2}^* \to \mathbb{Z}_{n^2}^*$ given by $f(x) = x^n$. We want to compute the size of the image of $f$.

The kernel of $f$ consists of the $x$ so $x^n = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{n^2}^*$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_{n^2}^* \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/(q-1)\mathbb{Z}$ and $n$ is relatively prime to $p-1, q-1$ we see that the kernel has size $n$ (the kernel consists of things of the form $(a, 0, 0)$ for $a \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$).

We know that the product of the sizes of the image and the kernel of $f$ is the size of $\mathbb{Z}_{n^2}^* = n\phi(n)$; hence the size of the image of $f$ is $n\phi(n)/n = \phi(n)$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{n^2}^*$ is **not** cyclic! That would mean that $n^2$ has a primitive root, but the only integers with primitive roots are primes, odd prime powers, twice an odd prime power, and $4$; $n^2$ is none of them.

Comment: Nice catch, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Mohit can you elaborate why $a ^ n = 1$ for $a \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$? Also why the kernel is not $(a, 1, 1)$?

Comment: I don't think I claimed $a^n = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Typically when we write $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ we mean the set $\{0, \dots, n-1 \}$ under addition mod n. Hence in this case we have $a + a + \dots + a = 0$ (where there are $n$ $a$'s being summed) not $a^n = 1$.

Comment: Concerning the kernel we just need to count the number of elements of period $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{n^2}^*$. One way to do this is to realize $\mathbb{Z}_{n^2}^*$ as a product of cyclic groups, in particular $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/(q-1)\mathbb{Z}$. In these cyclic groups I used additive notation so $(a,1,1)+(a,1,1)+\dots + (a,1,1) = (na,n,n) = (0,n,n) \neq (0,0,0)$ since $p-1$ doesn't divide $n$.